# Detecting Drop down with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, telerik, selenium-webdriver, radgrid, radgridview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4WUv.jpg

[Link to Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

I'm trying to detect the different drop downs on this page (depicted by the filters by the text boxes). The problem i'm having is that it seems that the filters all have the same ids. I can get the webdriver to find the initial filter button but not target the options in the drop down.

- Note the filters I'm talking about are the ones from the funnel buttons. For example contains, isEqual, between etc *

This is wrong but an example

```
it('Should filter grid to -contain Civic', function() {
    browser.element(by.id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl03_FilterTextBox_Model')).sendKeys("civic");
    browser.element(by.id('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl03$FilterTextBox_Model')).click(); 
    browser.element(by.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Contains')]")).click();
})
```

Comment: I see each of them with a different id, although dynamic which will make it useless as a selector. Do you have any code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Had a typo in the question. Any scripts I've tried it's getting stuck after I click the the filter drop down (which I can find) but it seems to not be able to find the options.. contains etc related to that specific filter.

Comment: Post your code! Post any errors! See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to associate the drop down options with the right filter button. If you look in the HTML It's disconnected from the path of the filter button itself and there is only one list of options on the html itself. You can't even inspect the element of the options and even using selenium ide as backup it doesn't give a path that would detect that specific drop down. I can give you the initial filter click code no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***NOTE**  The answer that was being looked for is at the bottom of this answer after the word "EDIT".  The rest of this answer is retained because it is still useful.*

It's a challenge to test webpages that dynamically generate ids and other attributes.  Sometimes you just have to figure out how to navigate the stable attributes with an xpath.  Here's an xpath that finds all four dropdowns:

```
//tr[@class='rgFilterRow']//input
```

To differentiate between each one, you can do this:

```
(//tr[@class='rgFilterRow']//input)[1]      // Brand Name
(//tr[@class='rgFilterRow']//input)[2]      // Classification
(//tr[@class='rgFilterRow']//input)[3]      // Transmission
(//tr[@class='rgFilterRow']//input)[4]      // Fuel
```

Using numbers to specify elements in an xpath isn't really desirable (it will behave incorrectly if the order of columns in the table changes), but it's probably the best you can do in this case because of all the dynamic ids and general lack of reliable identifying attributes.

**EDIT**

I misunderstood what you were trying to get because I didn't look at the image that you linked to.  Once you've opened up that menu, you should be able to use an xpath to get whichever option you want by the text.  For example, if you want the "Contains" option:

```
//a[@class='rmLink']//span[text()='Contains']
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. This definitely helps on the drop downs but the part i'm having problems with is the filter (the funnel buttons) drop downs that have contains isEqual, between etc

Comment: Thanks TJamesBoone. I'll try that. It's just been frustrating so far because I thought it was because both filters called the "same" list. It might be just that i'm not very good with regex or xpath. Thanks for keeping up with me!

Answer (score 0):

This page is highly dynamic. You had better brush up on your XPath, as nothing else will be able to help you. You can use this: http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html .

Here is a simple example of how to access the Brand Name "pulldown". This is written in Groovy, which looks a lot like Java. If you know Java you should be able to get the idea from this:

```
WebElement brandName = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl03_BrandNameCombo_Arrow"))
brandName.click()   // to open the "pulldown"
List<WebElement> brandItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='rcbList']/li"))
brandItems.each {
    if(it.text == 'BMW')
        it.click()
}
```

Unfortunately, the above `id` is not very reliable. A much better strategy would be something like:

```
WebElement classification = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@summary='combobox']//a[contains(@id, 'ClassificationCombo_Arrow')]"))
```

Selecting its items is done similarly.

```
classification.click()  // to open the "pulldown"
List<WebElement> classificationItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='rcbList']/li"))
classificationItems.each {
    if(it.text == 'Sedan')
        it.click()
}
```

If you are not up to the task, you should be able to get help from your development colleagues on how to locate all the elements in this page.

Comment: Thanks SiKing but I think my initial post was misleading. I meant filter as in the one with the funnel by it and basically runs sql type calls against the entered string.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? From all the code that everyone here has offered, you should be good to go. Or rewrite your initial question; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I haven't had time to try the suggestions yet. I just wanted to reply and say thanks since you took the time to reply.